# Procedure call inside another procedure with Exception handling. same Timestamp for all calls and not all calls executed in error case

Tags: postgresql

If got a simple procedure which does some logging handling for me:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE logging(name TEXT, message TEXT) 
BEGIN  
    INSERT INTO log_table
    SELECT NOW(), name,  message;
END
```

now i call my procedure several times from inside another procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE my_proc()
BEGIN
   CALL logging('my_proc', 'start');
   
   insert into myTable
   select * from another_table;
   
   CALL logging('my_proc', 'end');
   EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
     CALL logging('my_proc',SQLSTATE || ' - ' ||SQLERRM );
END
```

problem one:
When the procedure runs without exception, start and finish have the exact same timestamp, altough the query did take some time:

- "2022-11-16 15:11:01.322317"  "my_proc"   "start"
- "2022-11-16 15:11:01.322317"  "my_proc"   "end"

changing the procedure to use the timestamp as parameter instead of generating it inside the procedure gives the same behaviour

problem two:
when an error occurs, only the procedure call from within the exception will be executed, the start call will not be executed. So i only see the error message in my logging table, but not the start-Message.

So, how can i fix the timestamp so that he represents the time before and after the query instead of using the same time?

And how can i execute my first procedure call ('start'), even if an error with exception handling happens in the query afterwards?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split you code via different transactions. For example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE my_proc()
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $procedure$
BEGIN
    CALL logging('my_proc', 'start');
   
    begin
        insert into myTable
        select * from another_table;
   
        CALL logging('my_proc', 'end');
        EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
            CALL logging('my_proc',SQLSTATE || ' - ' ||SQLERRM );
    end;
END;
$procedure$
```

So, I explain you why you are gets same timestamp. On PostgreSQL `current_date` or `now()` gets same timestamp for same transactions. These are refreshing the time at the beginning of the transactions. You can use `clock_timestamp()`, this function is refreshing at the execution of the statement.