# how to manage a committed transaction and rollback

Tags: postgresql

I basically have two procs `Proc1` and `Proc2`, where the `Proc1` writes to a table and `Proc2` works upon data in the table.

so, the basic code would be:

```
Proc1(
// do some calculation
// insert into myTable data;
);  
 
Proc2(
//do some calulation find coef
//read data from myTable where data_stat > 3 + coef;
//update information in my table;
);
```

The problem is that both the proc have individual failure points, and since I need to work for `Proc2` after the data is written in the table, I want a behaviour like this:

```
START TRANSACTION;
   start transaction;
    x = CALL Proc1();
    if(x = true)
      COMMIT TRANSACTION;
    else ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;

   // the data is commited;
   y = CALL Proc2()
   if(y=true) COMMIT TRANSACTION;
   else ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
COMMIT TRANSACTION;
```

I was looking to use save points, but, it seems that doens't *temporarily commit* data, because after proc2 fails, I'd like to revert to the state before the Proc1 committed. So, what are my options to create the behaviour I want other than writing a reverse proc?

Comment: See  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74463296/procedure-call-inside-another-procedure-with-exception-handling-same-timestamp/74464907#74464907  Maybe it will help you

Comment: Since `proc1` and `proc2` return data, they are functions, not procedures, right? What keeps you from implementing the code the way you want?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe , actually, I've been using procedures with inout variables for returning values. The problem I think I have is that proc2 needs committed data, but, postgres doesn't allow a nested transaction.

Comment: Why would you need a nested transaction?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe , because, if Proc2 fails, I'd like to revert back to the state before proc1 committed.

Comment: Again, why do you need a nested transaction? What problem should it solve that cannot be solved any other way.

Comment: @FrankHeikens , could you tell me one way to revert without writing a custom revert proc, to revert to the state before proc1 committed, if proc2 happens to fail.

Comment: It's completely unclear why and if you have to rollback. Maybe a different solution works as well, could be even faster. Speaking for myself and the projects I did in PostgreSQL over the last 15 years, I never needed something like this. There was always a better (and faster!) solution.

Comment: yeah, I mean, I could rewrite my code, but was thinking of a way to rollout a first version quickly, because, it's already working and testing is a lot of work, but it seems I may have to refactor

Comment: I am still trying to figure out what your real need is. Why does `proc2` need the data committed? If `proc2` fails, should the modifications by `proc1` be undone or not?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe , postgres on separate transaction blocks doesn't see uncommitted data , isn't it? And..... yes, as I've mentioned above, if `proc2` fails, I'd like to revert to the state before `proc1` commits, which would basically mean to undo modifications by `proc1`.

Comment: Yes, uncommitted data are not visible outside the current transaction. But if you call `proc1` and `proc2` in the same transaction, `proc2` can see the results of `proc1`.